# Retrieve single object from list using java8 stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Employee`, and I want to retrieve only one `Employee` information with the specific name:

```
public static Employee getAllEmployeeDetails(String employeeName) {
    List<Employee> empList = getAllEmployeeDetails();
    Employee employee = empList.stream().filter(x -> x.equals(employeeName));
    return employee;
}
```

Please let me know how to filter the data and return a single element.

Comment: I’d suggest renaming your method to “getEmployeeByName” as opposed to “getAllEmployeeDetails”. readability is very important.

Answer (score 19):

This will locate the first `Employee` matching the given name, or `null` if not found:

```
Employee employee = empList.stream()
                           .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(employeeName))
                           .findFirst()
                           .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `findFirst` or `findAny`:

```
empList.stream()
       .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(employeeName))
.findFirst()
```

or

```
empList.stream()
       .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(employeeName))
.findAny();
```

However, I'd suggest changing the method return type with the use of `Optional` which is intended for use as a method return type where
there is a need to represent "no result" . in other words we let the "client" decide what to do in the "no value" case. i.e.

```
public static Optional<Employee> getAllEmployeeDetails(String employeeName) {
       return empList.stream()
           .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(employeeName))
          .findFirst()
}
```

you could have done `.findFirst().orElse(null)` but dealing with `nullity` is sometimes dangerous and this is a perfect opportunity to leverage the `Optional<T>` API.

Comment: Yup, this is indeed good advice: drop nulls, return Optionals.

Comment: or maybe `orElseThrow` if the get is critical based on the `employeeName`,  thoughts?

Comment: @nullpointer good shout! I’ll have to say it depends and is debatable but personally I’d proceed with the suggested approach because it provides more options to the client and the method signature with an Optional return type is very meaningful/readable.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use multiple ways to get single object from list here i just modified the method names and also some variable names so that the code should be readable and also try to use Optional as it handles null pointer

```
  public static Employee findEmployeeByName(String employeeName) {
    List<Employee> empList = getAllEmployeeDetails();
    Optional<Employee> employee = empList.stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(employeeName))
            .findFirst();
    return employee.isPresent() ? employee.get() : null; // Instead of null you can also return empty Employee Object
}
```